# Python - Best way to match list of words in long text

Tags: performance, python-2.7, pandas, text-mining

**Problem**:
I have a list of words (in a .txt file) with the names of programming languages and related technologies (one tech per line) such as:

```
AngularJS
Grunt
T-SQL
MySQL
SQL Server
SQL
Bash
Git
Android
Android Studio
Ajax
Design patterns
Frontend developer
```

and so on (the list contains around 250 terms, but it will definitely get bigger).

I also have a pandas dataframe with a column containing the full text of IT related job posts (one per row).

What I want to do is to add another column to the existing dataframe, keeping in that column a list of all the keywords (from the .txt file) that were found in the job description.

Example: the job description says "We're looking for a *frontend developer* with +3 years of experience using *Angular-JS*. Knowledge in *Grunt*, *git* and *design patterns* are a must..." then the list would be `['Frontend developer', 'AngularJS', 'Grunt', 'Git', 'Design patterns']`.

**My current (kind of  working) approach:**

```
# set_keywords contains a Python set with all keywords in the .txt file
lmb_extract_keywords = (lambda post: filter(None, set(w if w.lower() in post.lower() else None for w in set_keywords)))

# df_posts is a pandas dataframe with only one column containing one full post per row
df_posts['keywords'] = df_posts.apply(lmb_extract_keywords)
```

**Questions**:

1) Are there ways to make this more efficient ? (the pandas dataframe has nearly 10000 rows). I'm open to all kind of suggestions (regular expressions, text mining frameworks, etc).

2) In some cases I find repetitions of general terms in the output lists. Imagine that if the job descriptions said 'Android Studio' then the output list would be `['Android', 'Android Studio']` whereas I would want it to be `['Android Studio']`. Ways to avoid these cases ?

3) If the job description said *'front-end dev'* then I'd never find a match (though I do listed *frontend developer* in my .txt). Moreover, if the technology has a name such as `C`, then I always find it (any word with a c letter would match). Ways to fix these problems ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: was you questions answered?

Answer (score 1):

When **searching** for something, there are two ways to make it faster:

1. Don't care about exactness. Just **sample some words** from the text and do your search. However, there is a risk that you miss the word. I don't think that this is what you want.
2. **Order your text first**. Just extract all the words and order them alphabetically. You can put the words into bins depending on the first letter and not search all bins. Since your terms actually have more than 1 word, also save the index of each word in the text. With the index, you can go back to the text and see if the next word is also part of your terms.

The above pre-processing might seems like it takes a lot of time, but if your job descriptions are somewhat long, it will speed up your search.

To **avoid having repeated terms**:

1. Extract all term.
2. Order your terms on their length.
3. Go over the terms and check if they are a substring of a longer term. If so, remove it.

To deal with the **C**, extract each word as I mention above and do a strict comparison, not check for substrings.

To **detect terms that are spelled differently** you can:

1. Expand your term list.
2. Apply word normalization techniques, where you measure the distance between two words, and if that distance is above a threshold, you consider a match. Word distances could be Levenshtein, Jaro-Winkeler...